# PHP PDO display new data without user refreshing

Tags: php

An university assignment of me reads as follows (see image) **I am specifically focus on question C** now the question makes no sense to me!

**We are only allowed to use PHP**, so unless I missed something in the course, the answer is wrong.

We should display all data **without, user refreshing page**, *correct me if I am wrong but this is not possible without using some sort of javascript/ajax...?*

[image]

[You can view my code here on code pastebin:](http://pastebin.com/361Y2hQM)

Comment: Correct, there is no way(that I know of) to update page information without the use of ajax. This has nothing to do with PHP or any other programming language, it's in the nature of http protocol.

Comment: You cannot do it without javascript. AJAX -  Asynchronous Javascript and XML.

Answer (score 2):

When the form is submitted, that is already a new request (method=POST, type=multipart/form-data), so if you insert the data before you fetch data for the table you should be good for the assignment.